# Is "anglo" an acceptable substitute for "anglo-parlante"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, hispanoamérica, república-dominicana

Is "anglo" an acceptable substitute for "anglo-parlante" in Caribbean Spanish (specifically Dominican Republic)?

Comment: The DRAE accepts ["anglo"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2eMpGSA) as an equivalent of "perteneciente a la lengua anglosajona"

Comment: @Diego - Thanks.  I suppose there are two ways of understanding *anglo* -- the race of the person or the language the person speaks.  What I need help with is, if I just write "anglo" by itself, will it be understandable that I might be talking about the person's language(s), not necessarily the person's race or general culture?

Comment: I don't know, I would say that there is some ambiguity (that's why I posted as comment and not as an answer). I don't know if that ambiguity means that the answer for your question is a "no"... I would wait for a couple days more. I'm sure some else will be able to give some further insight about this matter.

Answer (score 1):

I speak South American Spanish as my first language, and I would clearly understand you are talking about someone from an English speaking country. I can't tell if this a correct form.